# AND in LEFT JOIN with Doctrine

Tags: doctrine-orm, doctrine

How can i add AND in LEFT JOIN like this SELECT * FROM photo LEFT JOIN liked_photo lp on photo.id = lp.photo_id AND lp.user_id = 6 WHERE photo.is_public = 1 ?

```
`{`
    `return $this->createQueryBuilder('photo')`
        `->leftJoin("photo.likedPhotos", "lp", "photo.id = lp.Photo")`
        `->addSelect('lp')`
        `->where('photo.is_public = 1')`
        `->orderBy('photo.uploaded_at', 'DESC')`
        `->getQuery();`
```

`}`

Comment: I need to left join after using WHERE user_id = 6 on lp table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with :

```php
return $this->createQueryBuilder('photo')
        ->leftJoin("photo.likedPhotos", "lp", Join::WITH, "photo.id = lp.Photo AND lp.user_id = 6")
        ->addSelect('lp')
        ->where('photo.is_public = 1')
        ->orderBy('photo.uploaded_at', 'DESC')
        ->getQuery();
```

See doctrine doc : https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.9/reference/query-builder.html#line-number-5775ab09aefa638b14c776a733b4b61d2e324b74-43